# Как получить масив из URLSession?

Tags: swift, api

Пытаюсь сделать программу для сайта новостей. Я беру информацию из сайта через апи, все работает прекрасно.

Только вопрос, как мне вывести этот массив из цикла?

Вот мой код:

```
func getUsers(){

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let dataResponse = data,
              error == nil else {
              print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
              return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                                   dataResponse, options: [])
           // print(jsonResponse) //Response result
            guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                  return
            }
          // print(jsonArray)
            //Now get title value
            guard let href = jsonArray[0]["href"] as? String else { return };
            guard let site = jsonArray[0]["site"] as? String else { return };
           // guard let title = jsonArray[0]["tittle"] as? String? else { return };
            guard let time = jsonArray[0]["time"] as? String else { return };
            //print(href)
           // print(site)
            //print(title)
           // print(time)//compiler outout -  delectus aut autem
            struct News{
               var href: String

               var site: String

                var time: String

            }

            self.news = News(href: href, site: site, time:time)


         } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
       }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял, Вам нужно переделать функцию, чтобы она возвращала массив. Попробуйте так:

```
func getUsers() -> [News] {
     var newsArray = [News]()
     ...
     newsArray.append(news)
     return newsArray
}
```